# Should I downsample because of overrepresentation of geographic locations in time series data

Tags: classification, data-preprocessing, time-series

I am in the start of working with a project where I am hoping to be able to classify activities based time series data. I have historic data; lat/long/speed/(..) as well as the activity.

The challenge is that I have two sources for these data - one is having a short range but high detection (fixed equipment on ground) and the other have high range and low detection (satellite). This means that there is a 10-1 amount of data in favor for the source with short range. But the coverage for the high range is twice as good.

I worry that this will lead to that the data that is picked up by the short range detection will be overrepresented in any future classifications.

One idea I have is to down sample the data to a time-scale where the time-density of the data is more or less the same, which means bringing the high detection source "down" to level with the high coverage one.